# IoT Hub SDK - DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate - linux container

Tags: containers, azure-iot-hub

When using IoT Hub SDK in linux container, is there a way to specify the certificate whose private key is in TPM to use for Device Authentication(not using TPM Attestation).  The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceauthenticationwithx509certificate?view=azure-dotnet  that the certificate private key has to be in cert store(which we can do in windows) or in the object itself(which is not secure). Anyone has experience using this in a linux container with certificate authentication for the device ?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!